# rdiff-backup incrementing files that didn't change in years

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup, rsync, rdiff-backup

I'm running Linux on a laptop, recently the hard drive is failing. The system that's running off of this drive freezes seconds after the desktop is loaded.

I want to make the last incremental backup from a LiveCD Linux system before I replace the drive and copy the files back to make sure no work is lost.

I was making near-daily incemental backups with rdiff-backup using a custom script wrapper and the backups always thake about 5 - 20 minutes.

Now I started to make a final increment to the backup (knowing there was little changed since last backup), but rdiff-backup is taking ages to complete this. I'm looking at the console output (using -v9 opting to list all actions) and it's clearly incrementing files that haven't changed in years. They are also files that no system process needs or uses.

I wondered if maybe the LiveCD system's date is wrong - only the timezone was wrong. But that shouldn't make the year+ old files to suddenly appear touched to rsync (that is being used by rdiff-backup).

```
(...)
Current mirror: Fri Oct 14 23:55:32 2016
$ date
Mon Oct 17 20:02:21 CEST 2016
```

When I re-run the backup lit looks like I'm making a completely new one.

What is going on? Am I missing something?

I've double checked the input and output directories, I have no idea what's happening.